# How are pointers working on C

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct

I'd like to ask for some good tutorial so I can understand how really works the C pointers. I've got here a piece of code to give you an example.
I got this function:

```
typedef struct parameCli {
    int id ;
    int attend;
    int wait;
    int print;
}Cli;
Cli *clients;
void newUser(void *arg){
if (cUser<=u)
    {
    cUser++;
    clients->id=cUser;
    printf("Client %d has entered. \n",cUser);
    }
}
```

And the main is something like that:

```
int main(){
printf("How many clients do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d",&u);
    struct parameCli p1[u] ;
    pthread_t clients[u];
    for (i = 0; i < u; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&clients[i],NULL,newUser,(void*)&p1[i]);
        pthread_join (clients[i],NULL);
    }
return 0
}
```

I don't understand how void* or *args are working and how should it be written because of what. When I'm running that code, I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/include/pthread.h:232:12: note: wanted ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is ‘void (*)(void *)’ (Translated from another language)
```

Thank everybody.

Comment: A pointer is not "working" or "not working" in itself. You need to explain **what specifically** you don't understand. As to the compiler error, it has almost nothing to do with pointers; `pthread_create` expects a function pointer that returns `void *`, but you passed it a function pointer that returns `void`, that's all.

Comment: `newUser` should return `void *`.

Comment: What I don't understand is when, where and why must I use pointers.

Comment: @RzvGG That's quite broad. Arrays and specifically strings have a strong relation to pointers; if you want simulate pass-by-reference, you have to use pointers, etc. Perhaps you just need a good beginner C book to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Pointers are just a reference to another variable. So in the Pointer itself is just an adress from the memory stored.

For example Pointers are used for:

- to allocate memory dynamically (in that case the compiler can't give an adress for the memory because the adress is determined during the programm)
- "Call-by-reference" in functions (so you can change variables from the calling instance; Technically on Compilerlevel a pointer is no call-by-reference, but it has nearly the same effect)
- With functionpointers you can give a function as a parameter to another function.
- lists and trees needs normally pointers

As H2CO3 said a good beginner book for C will help you to start. (If you can read german http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/c_von_a_bis_z/000_c_vorwort_001.htm#mj764cb3fd439d3b95d1843e7c7d17f235 is a good one)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start simpler. You have a lot going on in this little program.

Dr. Plank has a classic intro to pointers.

http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/classes/cs140/Notes/Pointers/index.html

C code:

```
main()
{
  int i;
  int *ip1;

  ip1 = &i;

  i = 5;
  printf("i: %2d    *ip1: %2d\n", i, *ip1);

  *ip1 = 10;
  printf("i: %2d    *ip1: %2d\n", i, *ip1);

  i = 15;
  printf("i: %2d    *ip1: %2d\n", i, *ip1);
}
```

Compile and run the program:

```
$ gcc test.cpp
$ ./a.out 
i:  5    *ip1:  5
i: 10    *ip1: 10
i: 15    *ip1: 15
```

Later on try to understand function pointers and parameters like void *arg.